# Hide PUBLIC posts in the LOOP from LOGGED-IN users

Tags: posts, private

I am trying to achieve this:

**When users are logged in, and they look at the loop in Home page, they should see ONLY private posts.**

Public posts should be hidden from them, as they are redundant.

I tried many variations, to no avail:

```
function exclude_public_posts_from_front_page($query) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        // Modify the query to include only private posts
        $query->set('post_status', array('private'));
    }
}

// Hook into the 'pre_get_posts' action
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_public_posts_from_front_page');
```

or:

```
function exclude_public_posts_for_logged_in_users($clauses, $query) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND post_status = 'private'";
    }
    return $clauses;
}

// Hook into the 'posts_clauses' filter
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'exclude_public_posts_for_logged_in_users', 10, 2);
```

or:

```
function exclude_public_posts_from_front_page($query) {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Exclude all public posts from the query
        $query->set('post_status', array('private'));
    }

    return $query;
}

// Hook into the 'pre_get_posts' action
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_public_posts_from_front_page');
```

Somehow the logged in user is always shown ALL posts, private and public.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Does it work if you use `$query->is_user_logged_in()` (and `$query->is_home()`) per [the warning about conditional functions on the `pre_get_posts` doc page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#a-warning-about-conditional-functions)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no, same result. Logged in users are still shown public posts.